# In Ticket to Ride: Märklin, do Passenger cards allow you to complete Destination tickets?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Based on my understanding of the rules, you can use a Passenger card to complete a route that a passenger is on.  So, if I have a route of red trains and someone places blue in my path I can use the passenger card when picking up tokens to complete my destination.

**At the end of the game do I get to count that as a completed Destination ticket (even though there is a break in my trains)?** OR

**Is the destination ONLY counted when the Passenger travels through and picks up Merchandise tokens?**

Comment: What is a Passenger *ticket*? [The rules](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tm_rules_en.pdf) say that Passenger Cards are drawn like train cards, but they don't allow you to complete routes, they are used in the **3. Move Passenger step** , "Passenger Cards can be drawn like  any other Train cards. When moving a Passenger, the player can play any number of Passenger Cards and use one route belonging to an opponent for each Passenger Card played."

Comment: I have edited the question in an attempt to clarify it, using the standard game terms. @michele, if I have misunderstood the intent of the question, let me know.

Comment: Okay, so if I am understanding this correctly destinations need to be completed as in every other version of ttr. However, when my passenger is moving along and picking up tokens she can detour along another players route and pick up her tokens ad long as a passenger card is played for each route. Is that it?  If so, does the passenger ultimately need to get back on the players track and end at the destination or can the passenger end somewhere on an opponent's route?

Comment: The passenger can end wherever.  You don't have to end them on your route.  One weird quirk; you can send the passenger fram city A to B and back again, if they use one player's route one way, and another player's route the other way, using passenger cards.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that **passenger cards are not used to claim routes**. Although they are drawn like train cards, they are not played when claiming a route. They are played only when using the Move Passengers action to collect Merchandise tokens from cities. Each passenger card played allows you to move your passenger through one route belonging to another player.

Excerpts from the rulebook:

> [When Moving a Passenger] The player may move any one of his Passengers that is already on the board. The Passenger must move from the city he currently occupies along any or all of the player's continuous routes, picking up one Merchandise Token from each city
>   he moves. The player can only use the same route once per turn, i.e., a Passenger may
>   not backtrack over the same route. The player does not pick up a Merchandise Token in the city in which the Passenger starts. At the end of the turn the Passenger that moves is removed from the game.

And the role of the passenger cards:

> When moving a Passenger, the player can play any number of Passenger Cards and use one route belonging to an opponent for each Passenger Card played.

(p. 3-4 of the [rulebook](http://static.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tm_rules_en.pdf))

Passenger cards **do not give you any ability to use opponents' routes for any other purpose**, including completing tickets at the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

**No, using Passenger cards to move a Passenger between two cities on an opponents route does not allow you to add points for completed Destination Tickets at the end of the game.**

In the [rule book under](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tm_rules_en.pdf) **Calculating Scores** (page 6) and **Drawing Destination Ticket Cards**:

> Players should then reveal all their Destination Tickets and add (or subtract) the value of their Destination Tickets still in hand, based on **whether they successfully connected those cities together or not**.
>
> Each Destination Ticket includes the name of two cities on the map and a Point Value. **If a player successfully completes a series of routes that connect the two cities, he will add the amount of points indicated on the Destination Ticket to his point total at the end of the game.** If he does not successfully connect the two cities, he deducts the amount of points indicated.

You connect cities by claiming routes (Page 5)

> A route is a set of continuous colored spaces (in some instances, gray spaces) between two adjacent cities on the map. To claim a route, a player must play a set of Train Cards whose color and quantity match the color and number of spaces of the chosen route.

Passenger cards (10 total) are not used to claim routes, they are used during a Game Turn which a player chooses to 4. Move Passengers (page 3). The Passenger card allows you to move a Passenger through an opponents route.

> Passenger Cards can be drawn like any other Train cards. When moving a Passenger, the player can play any number of Passenger Cards and **use one route belonging to an opponent for each Passenger Card played**.